# MySQL Workbranch crushes when save EER Diagram on Debian

Tags: mysql-workbench

When tiring to save EER or read from file the MySQL Workbench dies...

MySQL Workbench version 6.3.10
Failing on Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that it cannot see "en_US.UTF-8" so you need to verifiy that

```
sudo vi /etc/locale.gen   # should have 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8'
sudo locale-gen
```

any you can run

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" mysql-workbench
```